# NaN appearing because of quotes within split property

Tags: javascript, split

I'm sorry if this has already been answered here, but I'm not entirely sure what to even look for. I've recently started learning to code as something I've seen as enjoyable. I used a website and it told me that I had learned all I needed to about javascript (though I don't think that's true). To get some practice and a better handle on it I decided to do some challenges. I was working on one and got it mostly right. It said to reverse any input string (I was not required to code how to input, at least I think). The input is str. I've gotten it to reverse all of the characters, including punctuation, except quotations. To input, the phrase is required to be in quotations. In my result, instead of having quotations, it has a NaN before the phrase.

Here is the code I made

```js
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    
    var strL = str.length;
    
    var strS = str.split("");
    
    for(var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){
     
     var strC = strC + strS[strL];
     
     strL = strL -1;
        
    }
  // code goes here  
  return strC; 
         
}
   
// keep this function call here 
FirstReverse(readline());
```

and if I input "Hello, world", I get NaNdlrow ,olleH. I'm new, so it would help if this can be put into simpler terms. what you see in the code is about the most advanced stuff I know.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just got NaNdlrow ,olle

Comment: `strS[strL]` will be undefined the first time through the loop. The highest index is `strS[strL-1]`.

Comment: just if you are not aware that there is a reverse function on arrays, since you already make your string into an array `return str.split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: There's also no need to use `str.split()`. You can access a character in the string with `str[strL]`.

Comment: No, I did not know that! That got rid of the NaN, but no quotes (the challenge wants "Hello" to be "olleH"), but thank you, though I still would like to know what was wrong with what I had.

Comment: You're right about the lack of need for the str.split(), thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting `NaN` is because you never initialized `strC`, and you're also accessing outside the `strS` array.

You should initialize `strC` to an empty string.

And to prevent accessing outside the array, initialize `strL` to `str.length-1`, since array indexes go from `0` to `length-1`.

And the loop should repeat when `i < str.length`, not `i <= str.length`, otherwise you'll go past the beginning as well.

```js
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    
    var strL = str.length-1;
    var strS = str.split("");
    var strC = "";
    
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
     strC = strC + strS[strL];
     strL--;
        
    }
  // code goes here  
  return strC; 
         
}
   
// keep this function call here 
console.log(FirstReverse("abcdef"));
```

Comment: Another option would be to have the loop start from length-1 and go down to 0 and use `i` as the array index instead of `strL` which could be removed. Something like `for(var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { strC = strC + strS[i]; }`

Comment: @csmckelvey Yes, there are a zillion different ways to code this, like `strS[strS.length - 1 - i]`, or `for (strL = strS.length-1; strL >= 0; strL--)`

Comment: I decided to keep the structure as close to his original code as possible, just fixing the bugs.

Comment: Agreed and upvoted, just want the OP to realize there are other ways than his initial approach.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped. To add the quotes, in the return I put return '"' + strC + '"'; . And that worked!

Comment: Why are quotes needed? Quotes are normally used as part of the syntax for string literals, they don't need to be actually in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find the mistake. Change the for cycle from 
`for(var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++)` to `for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)`. Let me know what happened after the changes were done!

Comment: when I do that, I put in "Did it work?" and got NaN?krow ti di instead of  "?krow ti diD"

Comment: with the <= I get NaN?krow ti diD, so it gets the full length.

Comment: "_Let me know what happend_" You should be testing this code yourself before posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch around your for loop and define strC to be blank. Since strC is undefined the first time you run `strC = strC + strS[i];` is causing the NaN problem. Also, it seems easier to start at str.length and decrement to 0. Lastly, as previously posted there's no need for the call to split.

```
    function FirstReverse(str) { 

    var strL = str.length-1;

    var strC = "";

      for(var i = strL; i >= 0; i--){
       strC = strC + str[i];        
      }
    // code goes here
    return strC;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function FirstReverse(str) 
{ 
   var strC = "";
   var strS = str.split("");
    
   for(var i = str.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {  
       strC += strS[i];
   }

   return strC;       
}
   
FirstReverse("hello, world");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple errors in your code that are leading you to that `"NaN"` at the beginning of your string.

1) You need to declare your `strC` variable outside of the loop so that it has an initial value of empty string, `var strC = "";`. Currently the first time through your loop it is `undefined`.

2) The second mistake is that the variable you are using for indexing the values, `strL`, starts off as the length of the input string, when it should be one less. This is because the array is zero-indexed so the last item in the array is at `strS[strS.length - 1]`. (`strS.length` and `str.length` in your code are the same)

For example: The string `"abc"` has a length of `3` and so `strS` would be equal to `["a", "b", "c"]` (also with a length of `3`) and so `strS[0]` is equal to `"a"` and `strS[2]` is equal to `"c"`. But since you are starting from the length itself instead of `length - 1`, on the first iteration of the loop you are asking for `strS[3]` which is `undefined`.

So for this issue, subtract one from the length when you initialize the variable: `var strL = str.length - 1;`

The reason this is resulting in the letters `"NaN"` is because in JavaScript `NaN` is a special value that means "Not a Number" and is represented when converted to a string as `"NaN"`.

On your first loop `strC` is `undefined` (the first issue) and `strS[strL]` is `undefined` (the second issue) so your statement translates to `var strC = undefined + undefined;`. In JavaScript `undefined + undefined` is treated as a mathematical expression and results in `NaN`.

So at the start of the second time through the loop, `strC` is equal to `NaN` and `strL` is now pointing to the last item in the array so you get the `"d"` from the end of `"Hello, world"`. So your statement translates to `strC = NaN + "d";`, the `NaN` is converted to a string since `+` is treated as the string concatenation operator and you end up with `"NaNd"` and then the rest of your loop runs through just fine.

There are some better ways of doing what you are trying to accomplish, but as you learn and practice more you'll figure them out and now you know why your code is doing what it is and where this weird `"NaN"` nonsense is coming from. :)

---

Also, I think that you seem confused as to why your input has quotes but not the output. You are inputting a string  with the content `Hello, world` but strings are represented in code surrounded by quotes ala `"Hello, world"` so you shouldn't get quotes in the output.

Oh, and just for clarity, your code corrected looks like this:

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
    var strL = str.length - 1;
    var strS = str.split("");
    var strC = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        strC = strC + strS[strL];
        strL = strL - 1;
    }
    return strC;
}
```

But there are simpler ways such as counting down from the input length using the loop counter itself:

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
    var strS = str.split("");
    var strC = "";
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        strC = strC + strS[i];
    }
    return strC;
}
```

And even accessing the string itself without bother with split:

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
    var strC = "";
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        strC = strC + str[i];
    }
    return strC;
}
```

Or even just using some built-in string and array functions:

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```